# Select a particular record from a table using checkboxes

Tags: html, checkbox

I would like to have records on a table be selected using a checkbox.

For example if I have a table that stores Name,Contact and Country of an individual. I would like to be able to select individual records using checkboxes and be able to submit their values to a database.

```
      Name      Contact           Country
      Sam       sam@test.com      India
      Jane      jane@test.com     USA
```

The database part is no issue, just need to be able to collect the values stored here.

Comment: Have you tried something and found yourself stuck?

Comment: Not yet. I'm quite new to HTML and I am unable to get the programming logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of different ways you could go about this task. I'll present one way.

The idea is that you get a list of all the checkboxes(input elements, of type `checkbox`) in the (html) table of interest. From there, if the box is chcked, you find out which cell element contains it. You then find which (html) table row contains that cell. You can then use the `cells` collection of that row to get the various pieces of data in that row.

**HTML**

```
<table id='infoTable'>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th><th>Selected</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Sam</td><td>sam@test.com</td><td>India</td><td><input type='checkbox'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jane</td><td>jane@test.com</td><td>USA</td><td><input type='checkbox'/></td></tr>
</table>
<button onclick='showSelected()'>Show selected</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showSelected()
{
    // get all checkbox elements that exist in the table of interest
    var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('#infoTable input');

    var i, n = checkBoxes.length;
    var msg = 'Selected items:\n';

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var curCheckbox = checkBoxes[i];
        if (curCheckbox.checked == true)
        {
            var containingCell = curCheckbox.parentNode;
            var containingRow = containingCell.parentNode;

            var curName = containingRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
            var curContact = containingRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
            var curCountry = containingRow.cells[2].innerHTML;

            msg += curName + ' - ' + curContact + ' - ' + curCountry + '\n';
        }
    }
    alert(msg);
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/xphaL/